# Saving mp3 file to client?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to save a mp3 file from the server to the client and play it after that. I am loading the playlist and after that trying to play a song(The song is supposed to be saved on the client PC and played after that). I am building the application with JavaFXpackage main;

Controller class:

public class AudioController {

```
@FXML
private ResourceBundle resources;

@FXML
private URL location;

@FXML
private Button nextButton;

@FXML
private Button playButton;

@FXML
private ListView<String> playlist;

@FXML
private Button previousButton;

@FXML
private Button stopButton;

@FXML
void initialize() {
    final AudioClient audioClient = new AudioClient("127.0.0.1", 3000);
    audioClient.setUpConnection();

    ArrayList<String> songList = audioClient.getPlaylist();
    ObservableList<String> songs = FXCollections
            .observableArrayList(songList);
    playlist.setItems(songs);



    playButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            String songToPlay = playlist.getSelectionModel()
                    .getSelectedItem();
            if (songToPlay != null) {
                try {
                    String linkToSong = audioClient.getSong(songToPlay);
                    Media song = new Media(linkToSong);
                    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(song);
                    mediaPlayer.play();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

Client class

```
public class AudioClient {
protected BufferedReader socketReader;
protected PrintWriter socketWriter;
protected InputStream is;
protected String hostIP;
protected int hostPort;


public AudioClient(String hostIP, int hostPort) {
    this.hostIP = hostIP;
    this.hostPort = hostPort;
}

public ArrayList<String> getPlaylist() {

    ArrayList<String> fileLines = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        socketWriter.println("Playlist");
        socketWriter.flush();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = socketReader.readLine()) != null) {
            fileLines.add(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("There was a problem reading");
    }
    return fileLines;
}

public String getSong(String songName) throws IOException {

    socketWriter.println("Request " + songName);
    socketWriter.flush();
    String filePath = new String("D:\\" + songName + ".mp3");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath));
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    int count;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    while ((count = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
        bos.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }

    return filePath;
}

public void setUpConnection() {
    try {
        Socket client = new Socket(hostIP, hostPort);
        socketReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                client.getInputStream()));
        InputStream is = client.getInputStream();
        socketWriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("Error setting up socket connection: unknown host at "
                        + hostIP + ":" + hostPort);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error setting up socket connection: " + e);
    }
}

public void tearDownConnection() {
    try {
        socketWriter.close();
        socketReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error tearing down socket connection: " + e);
    }
}
```

Class for handling connections to the server

```
public class ConnectionHandler implements Runnable {
private Socket socketToHandle;

public ConnectionHandler(Socket aSocketToHandle) {
    socketToHandle = aSocketToHandle;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        PrintWriter streamWriter = new PrintWriter(
                socketToHandle.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader streamReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(socketToHandle.getInputStream()));
        String songToPlay = null;
        while ((songToPlay = streamReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (songToPlay.equals("Playlist")) {
                File songsTxt = new File(
                        "D:/Universitet i dr/JAVA/AudioPlayer/src/main/media/songsList.txt");
                String song = null;
                try {
                    FileReader reader = new FileReader(songsTxt);
                    BufferedReader songReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
                    while ((song = songReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        streamWriter.println(song);
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println("File dosen't exist");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Can't read from the file");
                }
            } else if (songToPlay.startsWith("Request ")) {
                songToPlay = songToPlay.replaceFirst("Request ", "");

                File songPath = new File(
                        "D:/Universitet i dr/JAVA/AudioPlayer/src/main/media/"
                                + songToPlay);
                BufferedInputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(
                        new FileInputStream(songPath));
                BufferedOutputStream outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                        socketToHandle.getOutputStream());
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                for (int read = inStream.read(buffer); read >= 0; read = inStream.read(buffer)) {
                    outStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error handling a client: " + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't send anything from the server except the playlist. Help please

Comment: What exactly happens when you run this code, and what are you expecting to happen? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: the playlist is loading in the listView and when I try to play a song I get a nullPointerException, the file is created but it is with size 0kb